# UIView: rotation + movement

Tags: iphone, uiview

I'm trying to move and rotate a UIImageView. I'm not using Core Animation for this nor I can use it.

By the way, the core part of the animation is what follows:

```
CGRect r = self.frame;
r.origin.y -= self.gravity + spring;
r.origin.x -= 1;
self.rotation -= 0.015;
self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rotation);
self.frame = r;
```

It almost works. I does move or it does rotate *in place*, but when I try to move *and* rotate it, it completely deforms skewing.

I've tried to move and then rotate and viceversa. I also tried various values for content mode with no luck. Any help?

**EDIT**

useful tutorial: http://www.permadi.com/blog/2009/05/iphone-sdk-bouncing-and-rotating-ball-example/

Comment: do you want both movement and rotation at the same time??? or individually?

Comment: at the same time. the movement is updated every tick within a method called by a NStimer

Comment: Why can't you use Core Animation? It makes this simple.

Comment: i need to animate the image according to a physical model. in my case, working with force vectors, gravity and the like to calculate x and y at every tick is far easier than having to generate bezier curves and time frames to fit the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to be sure what's going on without a picture of what you are seeing, but the following may be useful:

When you apply a rotation to a view it rotates it around (0,0), so you need to make sure you set the bounds of your view so that (0,0) is where you want the center of rotation. Suppose the image you are rotating is a 100x200 image and you want to rotate around the center of the image then you would need to say `self.bounds = CGMakeRect(-50, -100, 100, 200);` If you don't do this it will rotate about it's upper-left corner making sort of a spiral.

Oh, and using `self.center` to set the view's position seems to be more predictable than using `self.frame` when you have applied a rotation.

Here's some demo code that might make it easier to understand. In this case the code that does the animation is the view controller, but you should get the idea:

```
#define USE_SELF_CENTER 0

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.rotation = 0.0f;
    self.translation = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2.0f, 0.0);

    ObjectView* ov = [[ObjectView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f)];
#if USE_SELF_CENTER==1
    ov.center = self.translation;
#else
    ov.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(self.translation.x, self.translation.y);
#endif
    // adjust bounds for center of rotation
    ov.bounds = CGRectMake(-50.0f, -50.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f);
    [self.view addSubview:ov];
    self.objectView = ov;
    [ov release];

    NSTimer *aTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(nextFrame)
                                            userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    self.timer = aTimer;
    [aTimer  release];
    [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:self.timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
}



- (void)nextFrame
{
    NSLog(@"nextFrame");
    self.rotation += (5.0 / 180.0f * M_PI);
    self.translation = CGPointMake(self.translation.x, self.translation.y + 2.0);

#if USE_SELF_CENTER==1
    CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(self.rotation);
    self.objectView.center = self.translation;
    self.objectView.transform = t;
#else
    CGAffineTransform rot = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(self.rotation);
    CGAffineTransform txy = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(self.translation.x, self.translation.y);
    CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformConcat(rot, txy);
    self.objectView.transform = t;
#endif
}
```

The code demonstrates two ways of doing what you want. If `USE_SELF_CENTER` is zero then all the animation is done via transforms. If `USE_SELF_CENTER` is non-zero a transform is used for rotation and the translation is accomplished by setting the center of the view.

Answer (score 1):

use something like this, the idea is combine both the transformation i.e.

```
CGAffineTransform transforms = CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-1, -(self.gravity + spring)),CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rotation));
self.transform = transforms;
```

Hope this will work

Comment: thanks for the hint, but unfortunately it doesn't work :( i get the very same result

Answer (score 0):

Hello Friend please use this steps. On your XIB, take UIImageView and set Image and set its IBOutlet.

In .h file

```
 int theta;
 NSTimer *tmrAnimation;
 IBOutlet UIImageView *imgViewLoader;
```

In .m file

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad 
 {
     [super viewDidLoad];    
     theta = 0;
     tmrAnimation = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(animationImageViewLoader) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
 }
```

Add This function in your .m file.

```
 -(void)animationImageViewLoader
 {
     CGFloat angle = theta * (PI / 100);
     CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);
     theta = (theta + 1) % 200;
     imgViewLoader.transform = transform;
 }
```

**This code will help for Image Rotation only....**

Comment: hi, thanks for the code, but it is what i'm already doing. getting the rotation already works, my problem is having it working together with the animation.

Answer (score 0):

Following code helped me in achieving translation(vertical movement) and rotation together.

`CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -200);
    transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI);`

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self
                  duration:0.5
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent<br>
                animations:^{
                    [view setTransform:transform];
                }
                    completion:^(BOOL finished){
                }];
```

Hope this will help someone else...